# How do I get a result's status description instead of a status integer?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

This code snippet outputs `4` when the run was successful. Great! But how is displaying a number useful to anyone unless that person knows how / where to look up the status integer? I could perform a lookup but why recreate the wheel, right? Is there any built-in way to display the word "Succeeded", or the other 9 words found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000046000000) depending on status of an operation?

```
result = arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inputTable, outLocation, outFeatureClass)

print result.status
```

Comment: I think the real question is what are you after? Do you want to know its done? result.status > 3 Do you want actual messages? result.getMessages()

Comment: @KHibma instead of the status integer, I want the status description. result.getMessages() gives me a line describing what is executing, the "Start" time,  and "Succeeded at" time but not the simple, one word description. It's easier to work with the one word description than parse the getMessages() result to get a status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one option. The k:v mapping found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000046000000).

```
statusDictionary = {
    0: "New",
    1: "Submitted",
    2: "Waiting",
    3: "Executing",
    4: "Succeeded",
    5: "Failed",
    6: "Timed out",
    7: "Cancelling",
    8: "Cancelled",
    9: "Deleting",
    10: "Deleted"
}

print statusDictionary[arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inputTable, outLocation, outFeatureClass).status]
```